# Ejecutar textbox en C#

Tags: c#

Como puedo hacer para identificar el character **~** en un keypress. necesito hacer esto para un textbox, que cuando la persona escanee un numero ejecute las escaneo hasta que este complete y tenga los dos caracteres ~ el de inicio y el de fin ~.

```
private void formpress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        string buscar = "";

        if (e.KeyChar == char(126) )
        {


        }
    }
```

No tengo idea como implementar eso para que me ejecute el numero hasta que tenga el character de inicio y el de fin.
Si alguien me puede ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se si entiendo exactamente lo que pretendes, pero utiliza en lugar del evento `KeyPress` el `TextBox.TextChanged`. Sería algo asi:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.StartsWith("~") && textBox1.Text.EndsWith("~") && textBox1.Text.Length>1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("El texto está completo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, pues te va a resultar bastante difícil con el evento `KeyPress`, lo que yo te recomendaría es que utilices el evento `TextChanged`, el cual se ejecuta cada vez que el texto del control cambia (información [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) y [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)). Ahora bien, para verificar que haya al inicio y al final puedes usar algo como esto:

```
private void yourTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (yourTextBox.Text.Length > 3)
            {
                if (yourTextBox.Text [0] == '~' && yourTextBox.Text [textBox1.Text.Length - 1] == '~')
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

También puedes construir una expresión regular y verificarla por medio de esta (pero con expresiones regulares no tengo mucha experiencia), pero de igual manera, aquí te dejo un [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBsyqkxQzJ0) de YouTube, donde explican un poco sobre esto.

Comment: No estoy seguro si recomendaría ese video en particular para aprender expresiones regulares. Algunos recursos están listados en la [descripción de la etiqueta regex](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)